# Rotated DIV not preserving border-radius of its DIV parent

Tags: css, css-transforms

Question si simple:

I have parent DIV with border-radius:10px applied to it. Also has overflow:hidden;

Inside, there's another DIV which behaves as a rotated stripe that crosses its parent from left to right (width:120%).

Prblem with Chrome: Rotated text inside the strip is jagged. I apply following CSS trick to trigger anti-aliased:

`-webkit-transform:rotate(-3deg) translate3d(0,0,0); /*avoid jagged edges in chrome */`

That works, but as a side effect, the stripe no longer respects de border-radius of the parent DIV.

Why is that happening?
Note: **Must be tested in Chrome to see the problem**

http://jsfiddle.net/W89Me/

Comment: can you share your code through jsfiddle or codepen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Réponse encore plus simple:

Apply [`-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-style) like this to solve the problem

```
#parentdiv-xlz2 {
position: relative;
background-image: url("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/81/Sky_over_Washington_Monument.JPG");
background-size: contain;
padding-top: 0px;
height: 161px;
overflow: hidden;
border-radius: 15px;
-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
```

for performance reasons you can add [`backface-visibility`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/backface-visibility)to the child

```
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden ;
```

and  `perspective:` to the parent

```
  -webkit-perspective: 800;
```

## [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/W89Me/1/)

[image]

**Extra:** Here is the basic css3D structure.

MARKUP:

```
<div class=parent>
     <div class=preserve-3d>
           <div class=child>
                 lorem ipsum
           </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

STYLE:

```
[class=parent]{-webkit-perspective: 800;}
[class=preserve-3d]{-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;}   
[class=child]{-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden ;}
```

maybe this from(Ana Tudor) will help you too [How Nesting 3D Transformed Elements Works](http://davidwalsh.name/3d-transforms)

Test on [Google Chrome Browser](https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/) 
[image]